# reading and writing from file

Tags: linux, bash, locale, glibc

I have many questions about linux locales and especially different encodings.
1. Which locale is used when I perform the following command in bash?

```
// Привет - Russian "Hello"
echo "Привет" > ./test.txt
```

As I understand it should use locale which is getting by `locale` command.

After some experiments of changing locale I always get correct answer on my console by `cat ./test.txt`. **But why? Why when I change locale from `"ru_RU.iso88595"`, `"ru_RU.koi8r"`, etc. I always get correct result?**

Does this mean that in reality my locale is not changed? Or file encoding is independent to the current locale?

**Note:** when I set LC_ALL by `export LC_ALL="ru_RU.iso88595"` I get `bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (ru_RU.iso88595)`, but `echo $?` gives me `0` and later `locale` returns new locale. Is this locale really set?

Comment: Locale does not change file contents. Also, what characters you see depends on the settings of the terminal, not locale.

Comment: Ok, but for why is using locale which has encoding also like "en_US.UTF-8" or "en_US.iso88595"? I mean as I understand locale doesn't change file content but change what you will see when, for example done `cat ./test.txt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Which locale is used when I perform the following command in bash?
>
> `echo "Привет" > ./test.txt`

None. The data is written verbatim as it appears between the quotes. If the file is UTF-8, it will be written as UTF-8.

> Why when I change locale from "ru_RU.iso88595", "ru_RU.koi8r", etc. I always get correct result?

`cat somefile` just dumps the file verbatim to your terminal. cat's and/or your shell's locale is not involved. The terminal shows it in whichever way it's been configured (and if you're using `screen`, it has its own input and output configuration separate from the shell and terminal).

> I get bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (ru_RU.iso88595)

This is a message from Bash saying that it's having problems applying the new locale to the current session. You may have set the locale, but to an invalid value. Make sure it appears in the output of `locale -a`, otherwise it's not installed.

Comment: What encoding will be used when test.txt is created by this command and didn't exist before? The terminal encoding?

Comment: As mentioned, it will use the encoding of the command. If you use a koi8r terminal and write and run a koi8r command, the data will be written as koi8r. If you use a UTF-8 terminal, write a UTF-8 command into a UTF-8 file, then run the file from a koi8r terminal, it will be UTF-8.